# Issue with @ionic-native/network module

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been stuck at this issue with @ionic-native/network plugin for days and I'm unable to find a solution. I'm relatively new with Ionic, so excuse my code. The guide I followed to implement offline mode is this:
https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-offline-mode/

This is my Ionic info:

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.6 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : not installed
   @capacitor/core : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8 

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/dimiftb/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.10.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test_location_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/stepcounter": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "0.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-stepcounter": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "5.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.0.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-stepcounter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've imported the network module like this:

```
import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network';
```

The error I get is:

```
TS2749: 'Network' refers to a 'value', but it's being used as a 'type' here.
```

at

```
constructor(private network: Network, private toastController: ToastController, private plt: Platform)
```

Also when I adding the module to providers in app.module the error I get is:

```
TS2332: Type 'NetworkOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
```

I read online that that's due to the version of the package I'm using, so I tried to update to the latest version of @ionic-native/network as well and then import like this:

```
import {Network} from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
```

That clears those errors and I can include it as a provider and also add it to constructor as a type:

```
 private network: Network
```

however when I try to use it like this:

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
                console.log('WE ARE OFFLINE');
                this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Offline);
            }
        });
```

The error that I get is this:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Network.onDisconnect (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:104490:126)
    at NetworkService.webpackJsonp.174.NetworkService.initializeNetworkEvents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:446:22)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:439:19
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14356)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4373:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14296)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9523)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19622
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15040)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4364:33)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19132)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19653
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15040)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4364:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14961)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10214)
    at o (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7274)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16203)
    at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:26993)
    at HTMLDocument.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27238)
```

I'm really not sure what to do. I appreciate your help.

Comment: So you should not use /ngx route unless you are on Ionic 4 / Angular 7+ version. In your case I think you need to play around with pre version 5 ionic plugin and cordova plugins.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko there is no version 5 of Ionic yet. Version 5 refers to the Ionic CLI tools but this is not relevant to the question.

Comment: if you are using ngx import route it means you are using plugin version 5+ it has nothing to do with you cli version...

Comment: you are using Ionic 3 and have tagged it Ionic3 but then mention lots of Ionic 4 things, like the tutorial you are following says Ionic 4 in the url, and mentioning using `/ngx`. This is not right and is basically a mess. What you need to do is follow an Ionic 3 tutorial if you are working in Ionic 3. What you're asking us to do is to pick apart an app thats been messed up with incompatible frameworks and tutorials which is not something anyone should do.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the correct way to use the Network module in Ionic 4:**

1. Import the module in `app.module.ts` and add it to your providers:

```
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia/ngx';

@NgModule({
    [...]
    providers: [
        Network
    ]
})
```

2. In your page component import and inject the module:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';

export class WhateverPageComponent {

    constructor(
        private network: Network
    ) {
        [...]
    }
```

3. Subscribe to the network events you want to observe, for example:

```
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Network was disconnected');
});

let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Network was connected');
});
```

Comment: The op has been confusing about this, but I dont think this is correct for them as they seem to be using Ionic3 :)